# Why aren't Camera.unproject() and Camera.project() inverses of each other in libGdx?

Tags: libgdx

It's even written in the doc that [`Camera.unproject()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) assumes that the screen has it'origin in the top left corner, on the other hand [`Camera.project()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) assumes that the screen has its origin in the bottom left corner. This is so annoying. Is this intentional? Am I not getting something?

```
        tmp3.x = selected.pos.x;
        tmp3.y = selected.pos.y;
        camera.unproject(tmp3);
        camera.project(tmp3);
```

This flips the vector, where it should return the same vector.

**EDIT:**
First I was trying to use [`Viewport.project()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html#project-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) and [`Viewport.unproject()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) to convert points from one viewport to another (to position a context menu over a game element).They also inherit this naming confusion, and it's not even mentioned in the javadocs there.

**PS.** I really like libGdx. I've just written this to maybe spare some headache for someone in the future as I didn't find this anywhere on the web pointed out directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for the project method explains why. I think the assumption is that the most common reason to project a point is to line something up with the UI which will also be Y-up. But when I projecting, it is most likely to convert a touch coordinate to world coordinates.

Or in another way of looking at it, everything you do in OpenGL is Y-up so everything's designed to be Y-up or to get you there.

Not saying this is necessarily the best way; just trying to guess at the thought process. It probably wouldn't hurt to submit a PR for another type of project method of you need one, or you could subclass whichever type of camera you're using and add the additional method.

Comment: I guess you are right. I was just really annoyed because I wasted a few hours tracking a bug, because I thought I could safely assume that these two methods are in pair and that was the last place I looked. I just find it a poor design choice that the difference isn't reflected in the naming.